# Swift UITableViewCell view behind Disclosure Indicator background is not changing in bright mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have problems changing background color of UITableViewCell.

I set background color of Cell as UIColor.systemGray6
But color around disclosure indicator is still white. But in dark mode, it works properly like images below:

[image]
[image]

Here's my code for cell that contains Disclosure indicator:

```swift
class SettingsDiscolsureCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray6
        self.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: UIFont.labelFontSize)
        
        self.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I tried `self.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = .systemGray6` but noting changed

Why this happens and what should I do to change entire background color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of assigning color to contentView of UITableViewCell, use this

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray6
```

Your background color of cell will show below the accessoryType